# Yii2 $_GET and Yii::$app->request->get() not working

Tags: php, yii, get, yii2

**Background**

I'm having an odd issue with a simple line of code that I don't understand. I have an Action on a Controller that i'm using for LinkedIn auth. The first time the user hits the controller it redirects to the LinkedIn site for authentication, once the user authenticates linked in redirects back to the same controller with the auth code in the url as a param.

`http://beta.consynki.com/authentication/network/linkedin?code=DQTdGfxIlbsU...`

**Controller**

```
class AuthenticationController extends WebController {

    public function actionNetwork($network){
        $access_token = Yii::$app->request->get('code');

        $network_connection      = NetworkFactory::build($network);
        $client = $network_connection->getClient();

        if($access_token && !is_null($access_token)){

            $headers = Yii::$app->response->headers;
            $headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
            $headers->add('X-Access-Token', $access_token);

            return $this->render('success');
        }

        return $this->redirect($client->getLoginUrl(),302)->send();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1 - WebController**

```
/**
 * Class WebController
 *
 * Default controller for public web pages. This class pulls meta tags from a seporately stored file, and makes
 * them available to the view.
 *
 * @package www\components
 */
class WebController extends Controller {

    public $meta = [];

    public function beforeAction($event) {

        $controller = $this->id;
        $action     = $this->action->id;
        $meta_file  = Yii::getAlias('@www') . '/meta/' . $controller . '/' . $action . '.php';

        if (file_exists($meta_file)) {
            $this->meta = include($meta_file);
            $this->setMetaTags($this->meta);
        }

        return parent::beforeAction($event);
    }

    /**
     * Set the meta tags for a page
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @param        $tag
     * @param        $value
     */
    public function registerMetaTag($type = 'name', $tag, $value) {

        if (!is_null($value)) {
            $this->view->registerMetaTag([
                $type     => $tag,
                'content' => $value
            ]);
        }

    }

    public function behaviors() {
        return [

            /**
             * The particular campaign used.
             *
             * Example social_share, stay_connected_add
             */
            'utm_campaign' => [
                'class'        => 'common\behavior\TrackingBehavior',
                'queryParam'   => 'utm_campaign',
                'sessionParam' => 'utm_campaign',
            ],

            /*
             * The source of the referral, could be an add network, facebook, email or just a link on the Consynki site.
             *
             * example: google, facebook, citysearch, welcome_email
             */
            'utm_source'   => [
                'class'        => 'common\behavior\TrackingBehavior',
                'queryParam'   => 'utm_source',
                'sessionParam' => 'utm_source',
            ],
        ];
    }

    protected function setMetaTags($meta) {
        foreach ($meta AS $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $this->view->registerMetaTag($value, $key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

When I try to get the `code` from the GET param `Yii::$app->request->get('code');` I get a NULL value. On further inspection of the $_GET array `var_dump($app->request->get()` or `var_dump($_GET);` I see the key for the `code` variable has a $ `"?code"` in front of it. This is very odd.

`array(3) { ["network"]=> string(8) "linkedin" ["?code"]=> string(115) "DQTdGfxIlbsU..." ["state"]=> string(32) "12121..." }`

**Research Notes**

It looks like Yii2 modify's the $_GET value as it passes the url routing. Not sure if this is the issue. Have updated to the latest version of yii and it didn't fix the problem.

**Question**

Why would this happen? How can I fix it so that I can get the `code` value?

Comment: Are you sure `actionNetwork($network){`? Or, `actionLinkedin($network){`?

Comment: What is your UrlManager rule for this URL?

Comment: Hey @nana & @bizley, its `actionNetwork($network)`, my routing rule looks like this `'authentication/network/<network:\w+>'           => 'authentication/network',`

Comment: What is WebController ?

Comment: @soju, WebController  is a little class that extends the default Yii yii\web\Controller. It allows me set the meta tags that I store in a separate file. I have attached the class to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set rules there like this:

```
'authentication/network/<network:\w+>/<code:\w+>' => 'authentication/network',
'authentication/network/<network:\w+>' => 'authentication/network',
```

Now in action set parameters like:

```
public function actionNetwork($network, $code = null)
```

Your previous `$access_token` is now `$code`.

Comment: Thanks, this solution also seems to add the $ in front of the code key.

Comment: `$` or `?` How do you create the link in the first place?

Comment: Sorry `?` not `$` ['?code' => 'AbC...']. 

I provide a callback URL to LinkedIn as part of the oAuth request, LinkedIn add's the param `code` to the callback url when a user successfully authenticates. I can then get the code and use it to make authenticated API calls to LinkedIn.

Comment: Ok, try this - remove UrlManager rules for this action completely but keep the action parameters like I said and see if it helps.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are suggesting? Can you provide a little additional detail? I have also discovered this is an environmental issue, it seems to work fine in a new local dev environment. But not in my docker container local or in production.

Comment: I'm saying that you remove `'authentication/network/<network:\w+>' => 'authentication/network'` line from rules and see if you can catch `code` now. This way you should send `http://beta.consynki.com/authentication/network?network=linkedin` link and get `http://beta.consynki.com/authentication/network?network=linkedin&code=DQT...` in return.

Comment: That seems to be a good workaround and allowed the action to work. Still not sure what is causing the original problem with the GET param.